# validation data in jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable`, and I want validate data in the first column. When the user type the entry in any cell in the first column and click in another cell (focus lost), I want show message that the entry is false, and focus again in the cell until the entry is valid.

First I thought that the cell is like the `JTextFiled`, so I have tried the method `addFocusListener(...)` but it doesn't work!

```
table.getValueAt(0, 0).addFocusListener(
    new FocusListener() {
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        }

        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {

            for (int n = 0; n <= table.getValueAt(0, 0).toString().length(); n++) {

                if (Character.isDigit(table.getValueAt(0, 0).toString().charAt(n)) == false) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Error: code is a number !", "Error Message",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        break;
                    } else
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

creation of JTable:

```
 String [][]data={  {"-","-","0","-"},
                       {"-","-","0","-"},
                       {"-","-","0","-"},
                       {"-","-","0","-"},
                        {"-","-","0","-"},
                       {"-","-","0","-"},
                       {"-","-","0","-"},
                       {"-","-","0","-"}  };



     String[] header = {"Code Projet", "Description", "Duree", "Taches anterieurs"};


     table = new JTable(data, header);
```

Comment: Do have any code that you have implemented to try this?

Comment: Same as @mdewitt comment. We could post some examples, but what code have you tried so far? Can you edit your question and post some sample code that you have tried please?

Comment: first I thought that the cell in JTable is like a JTextField,so I I have tried the method addFocusListener..... but it doesn't work :\

Comment: Can you post the code? You can just edit this question and add the code to it

Comment: Can you add the code where you create the JTable please?

Comment: @mdewitt of course :)

Comment: I think for you, the best thing to do would be to create a TableCellEditor and add it to your table. Then you can use the TableCellEditor to do your validation

Comment: I can create cell editor for just one column!?
I don't know how does the tableCellEditor work!?

Answer (score 0):

The `TableCellEditor` that is added to a `JTable` will do any validation on the values that are entered into a `JTable`.

From the [Java Table Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#validtext):

> The automatic checking of user-entered strings occurs when the default
>   editor attempts to create a new instance of the class associated with
>   the cell's column. The default editor creates this instance using a
>   constructor that takes a String as an argument. For example, in a
>   column whose cells have type Integer, when the user types in "123" the
>   default editor creates the corresponding Integer using code equivalent
>   to new Integer("123"). If the constructor throws an exception, the
>   cell's outline turns red and refuses to let focus move out of the
>   cell. If you implement a class used as a column data type, you can use
>   the default editor if your class supplies a constructor that takes a
>   single argument of type String.

So, if you want to just make sure the user enters in an `Integer` (which is what it looks like from your code), you can set the column type to a type of `Integer` .

```
table.setDefaultEditor(Integer.class,
                       new IntegerEditor(0, 100));
```

Now the `DefaultCellEditor` will do the checking for you, and throw an exception if the type is not correct. You will just have to make sure you catch the exception and deal with it properly.

I think tutorial I linked above on creating tables would be very helpful for you, especially the part I linked to which talks about validating user text.